# How to display web pages on Android at native resolution

Tags: javascript, android

I have an Android TV now.

The system parameters are `1920 x 1080 px`  `960 x 540 dp`

I've finished a web page that I want to display on 1080p TV.

Through Android app's webview.

A 960 x 540 dp Android will let webview display in 960 x 540 px

This data comes from `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width` (javascript)

Is there a solution other than
`body{zoom:0.5}` 
and divide all px by two?

`body{ zoom:0.5 }`  doesn't work for me, maybe it's because I used echarts

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the perfect solution.

I didn't use `zoom` correctly before.

`zoom` is very effective

Now 960*540DP android behaves the same under 1080P web

```
  <style type="text/css">
      body {
           width: 200vw;
           height: 200vh;
           min-height: 200vh;
           zoom: 0.5 !important;
      }

      .mbody {
          height: 100%;
       }
  </style>
```

```
   <body>
       <div class="mbody">
       ...
       </div>
   </body>
```